# Group by more than 2 columns in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I want to group by more than 2 columns in SharePoint 2013.In OOTB we can do only 2 columns group by only,can any one help on this how i can achieve this functionality.

Please help on this,it is very show topper to us.

Comment: Can any one help on this with example please.

Comment: This is for SP 2010, but may get some idea http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html

Comment: We an able to find this url for SP 2013 http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want more than two groupings, you're going to have to build a custom page in either SharePoint Designer (the easier of the two methods), custom JavaScript (styling w/ CSS and web service calls w/ JS) or Visual Studio. No way around it, out of the box doesn't cover more than two groupings in the view customization.

Comment: Thanks Graham,Can any one help on this with example please.

Comment: We can able to find in this site for SP2013 http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html

Comment: Yep. That's the custom page in SharePoint Designer method I mentioned above.