# How to Group by more than 2 columns in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: list-view, grouping, design-manager

A year and a half back, a guy posted this question here in the community.

> [Group by more than 2 columns in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140578/group-by-more-than-2-columns-in-sharepoint-2013/Group%20by%20more%20than%202%20columns%20in%20SharePoint%202013?)

I read the answers and I followed the steps as provided in the given link

> http://www.dotnetsharepoint.com/2015/05/group-by-more-than-2-columns-sharepoint.html

If you open the link, you will see that you need to click on **Parse HTML** in order to get activate the **Data View** option.

I followed the same steps, but after clicking on **Parse HTML**, the Data View is **Not Activated**.

Can anyone please tell me what could be the possible reasons for the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you tried to edit your webpart page  in `Normal Mode`, not `Advanced Mode`.

**To Edit it in Advanced mode .**

- Open your Web Part Page > From the above ribbon click on Home > Click on `Advanced Mode`.

[image]

- Now you can continue your tutorial , by adding Empty data view Within ZoneTemplate tag as shown below

[image]