# Grouping 3 column in sharepoint list version sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

can I create grouping 3 columns on the sharepoint online version of the sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, you cannot get a 3 level group by in modern list view. There is little thing we can do to configure the modern experience view

For classic view you can try the old way, using SharePoint designer to hard code it：https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191894/how-to-group-by-more-than-2-columns-in-sharepoint-2013

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks your response. I have followed the steps in the article but at the stage (this picture is in the article)

[image]

But my appearance is not the same as the stage in the article.
This is my screen shoot:
[image]

In the article it says: Press Ctrl tab and select the columns that you want to give Group By, then click on Insert Selected Fields -> Click on Multiple Item View

When I Click on **Multiple Item View**, I got nothing.

Can you give me a solution? Thanks